# android inflating view at specific position onclick

Tags: android, android-inflate

I have a map window in my android app and I need that when user press on map (for example long press action) I want to inflate a view. Problem is that view should be inflated at user pressed x and y coordinates. See pic below.

[image]

I'm not using google maps, I'm using OSM and maspforge!. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your question? Are you wondering how to do this or is there an issue you're running into?

Comment: I'm wondering how to do this. I only know how to inflate view in top, bottom, right or left screen sides. But how to inflate at custom x and y screen coordinates? I have no idea how to do this (if it's possible)

Comment: Is this view supposed to just sit on top of the entire map view or do you want this view to be a "inside" of the map (i.e. pan around with the rest of the map when the user moves the map around)?

Comment: I need that view sit on top of the entire map